# facebook ios native like button stop working for my Facebook Page, but works for other Facebook Pages

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

We added native Like Button to our iOS and Android app.
Buttons works normally on both platforms.
We approved Like Button feature on facebook.
All worked fine until yesterday.
Yesterday, like button on iOS stops working.
Now when we tap on like buttton on iOS, system opens Safari, blank page with light-gray Facebook Logo appears, and then we automatically redirected back to the our app.
Same thing occurs when Facebook app installed - we go to Facebook app and then redirected back to our app.
On Android all is ok.
If we try to like other Facebook Page on iOS (not our Facebook Page), all is working fine.
We testing with our Developer user.
How to fix this?
What may be a reasons of such behaviour?

```
        likeButton = [FBLikeControl new];
        if(likeButton == nil)
            return;
        [likeButton autorelease];
        likeButton.objectID = @"https://www.facebook.com/PixelGun3DOfficial";
        likeButton.objectType = FBLikeControlObjectTypePage;
        likeButton.likeControlStyle = FBLikeControlStyleButton;
        likeButton.hidden = true;
        UIViewController* unityViewController = UnityGetGLViewController();
        if(unityViewController != nil && unityViewController.view != nil)
            [unityViewController.view addSubview:likeButton];
```

Comment: Can you provide some implementation code as to how you are implementing the like button and the page that you are trying to like?

Comment: @Bangdel code added, Page url in code

Comment: That looks like an old version of the SDK. Anyways, I tried this link of yours and it seems to work fine. It might be because you have already 'liked' your page?

Comment: @Bangdel  I liked my page once, then I disliked it back. Do you think this may be a reason for Like Button to not work again?